# Could a portable hole be stitched onto an item of clothing?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items

I'd like to introduce a new PC into a party, but allow him some gear and give the party a portable hole. I like the idea of a character preparing an emergency kit and stashing it in a portable hole and keeping the portable hole with them in secret, in case they're captured.

In D&D 5e, would it be possible to fold and stitch a portable hole as a patch onto a pair of trousers, similar to a patch from a [Robe of Useful Items](http://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/SRD:Robe_of_Useful_Items), without being damaged? If not, is it possible with any particular consequences? The intent is to remove and activate in emergencies, like an emergency kit with replacement clothes, weapons etc. Like the burn bag in The Bourne Identity, so the portable hole does not have to be usable in its stowed state.

Comment: Is there any reason why the person can't just have the portable hole folded up and tucked into a pocket?

Comment: @JNason if they're patted down when they're captured they'll have their pockets emptied.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## Nope - won't work.

Based upon 5E's description, it could be, but since it only functions when flat, stitching it in would render it unable to be unfolded.

The following is the important element from the DMG (p. 187):

> Folding the cloth closes the hole, and any creatures or
> objects within remain in the extradimensional space.

Further, the cloth is distinctive (according to older editions).

## In general...

Stitching through a magic item would generally be considered to damage the item.

The work around: place a patch over it, rather than making it the patch.

Comment: What's the significance of the cloth being distinctive?

Comment: Distinctive as in "easy to recognise", I guess. It'd be really hard to mistake the portable hole for a simple patch.