# What are the consequences of damaging a portable hole?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items

After asking [a question about stitching a portable hole](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/69821/could-a-portable-hole-be-stitched-onto-an-item-of-clothing/69824), and reading the DMG last night, I couldn't find any information on what happens to a portable hole if it's damaged.

I could assume the effects of damaging a Bag of Holding (the contents spilling onto the astral plane), but are there any defined effects of damage to or destruction of a portable hole, while in its unopened folded state?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

From the DMG p.141:

> **Magic Item Resilience**
>
> ... Most magic items, other than potions and scrolls, have resistance to all damage. Artifacts are practically indestructible, requiring extraordinary measures to destroy.

The *Portable Hole* isn't an artifact (*q.v.* DMG 219), so it only requires ordinary measures to destroy. It does take twice as long to destroy as a non-magical hole (hah!), but that's as far as the DMG takes us.

So any mutilation of your *Portable Hole* is going to go outside RAW, and you'll have to work with your DM to figure out if, how, and any consequences. (The effects you mention from *Bag of Holding* are certainly suggestive and may inform this discussion, but are not controlling.)

Answer (score -3):

A Portable Hole may be formed of special spider silk. However, it is still a pocket dimension and certainly not invulnerable.

Common sense and logic says a cut (rift) can be just as destructive as one in a bag of holding. It does not have to do with magic but the kinetic and potential energy of the molecules inside, which would not just disappear into nothing like popping a balloon in this dimension. Einstein's \$E=MC^2\$ establishes that energy cannot be created or destroyed.

Dimensional Rifts can cause very strange quantum physic effects because they exist in a different time-space-dimension in the continuum. The possibilities could include (DM's discretion) anything from a tiny supernova, to a tiny black hole, to an opening to the vacuum of space sucking out the atmosphere, to deadly poisonous gases from an alien atmosphere, to flaming gasses, to a star's flames, to a wormhole, to a paradoxical unexpected event, up to a portal to another dimension.

A portable hole is 2-sided and open, as it can be folded or rolled up but not closed like a bag of holding. So whatever the DM decides happens will be a 360 degree area of effect and stopping it would not be easy at all.

Comment: Welcome to the site! When you have a moment, please take the [tour]. The assumption when answering questions around here is they are backed up with personal experience, rules references, or both. In particular, I think the answer could do a better job of backing up how the rules apply to advanced physics in conjunction with the default magic system. Surely the Conjuration and Transmutation wizard schools violate some conservation laws :) Again, welcome to the site, and thanks for contributing.